# Laravel Sentinel Login with Webview App

Tags: laravel, webview, android-webview, laravel-5.1, cartalyst-sentinel

I have a web application built with Laravel 5.1.

I have opened a POST route on frontend for webview apps.

This is my app login function:

```
$json = array();

    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    $error = $this->auth->login($credentials, false);

    if (!$error) 
        $json['success'] = trans('user::messages.successfully logged in');

    else        
        $json['error'] = $error;

    echo json_encode($json);
```

However, when I redirect the mobile user to homepage after a successfull request, user is not logged in.

Interestingly, when I close and re-open the app, user is logged in.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I have discovered that when I put something in Session with login, it doesn't show up at Session. But when I close the app and re-open, Session restored.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the cookies both for after logging in and restarting the app after login from the debugbar? You may not be sending necessary cookies.